# extracting json inside json with jq

Tags: json, escaping, jq

I often find myself wanting to parse json with the `jq` command, but one of the values inside the json is an escaped string of json.

e.g. if I generate data with python like this:

```
import json
inner = {'a': 'b'}
outer = {'x': json.dumps(inner)}
json.dumps(outer)
```

I get:

```
{"x": "{\"a\": \"b\"}"}
```

How do I get `"b"` using the `jq` command?

```
$ echo '{"x": "{\"a\": \"b\"}"}' | jq .x
"{\"a\": \"b\"}"
```

Ok, that's the first step.
But the result isn't a json dictionary. It's a string that needs to be escaped and parsed into json.

`jq .x.a` throws an error: `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "a"`

Is there an argument I can add to `jq` to chain together two `jq` steps?
Or is there another command I can use instead?

e.g.

```
echo '{"x": "{\"a\": \"b\"}"}' | jq .x | jq --some-argument .a
```

or

```
echo '{"x": "{\"a\": \"b\"}"}' | jq .x | something-else | jq .a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following does the trick:

```
echo '{"x": "{\"a\": \"b\"}"}' | jq -r .x | jq .a
```

Here the `-r` step ensures that the output is **raw strings**, not JSON texts. Therefore:

```
"{\"a\": \"b\"}" -> {"a": "b"},
```

where this "raw string" can subsequently be taken as JSON input for `jq .a`, returning `"b"` (or `b` when used with `-r` flag).

**EDIT**: Calling `jq` twice is not ideal (thanks @peak), the previous command can be combined in this oneliner

```
| jq -r '.x|fromjson.a'
```

Comment: Yes I was aware that this solution was not ideal yet, wanted to check today how it could be improved. Thanks! Your solution doesn't work yet though, but i'm sure `fromstring` can be useful

Comment: In 1.6 i'm getting `jjq: error: fromstring/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.x|fromstring.a
jq: 1 compile error`

Comment: You're right. I meant: Avoid calling jq twice by using `fromjson`, e.g. `jq -r '.x|fromjson.a'`